# Поправить функцию, которая передаёт значение из словаря в формулу

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь авторов с их id:

```
b = {'Пятилетова Людмила Владимировна': 80000198, 'Скрябина Алёна Вячеславовна': 80000199, 'Шавель Светлана Ивановна': 80000200}
```

И есть списки авторов:

```
['Матюнин Владислав Александрович', 'Пятилетова Людмила Владимировна']
['Баутин Сергей Петрович', 'Дерябин Сергей Львович', 'Мезенцев Алексей Владимирович']
```

Они хранятся в переменной:

```
result
```

Формула:

```
#700: ^380000198^AПятилетова^BЛ. В.
```

Вот эту часть я уже получила:

```
^AПятилетова^BЛ. В.
```

И она хранится в переменной:

```
authors_b
```

Неказистая функция:

```
def get_author_id(name):
    for i in b:
        return b[i]

author_id = get_author_id(result)
```

В результате работы этой функции передается последнее значение из словаря. А мне нужно, чтобы значение соответствовало ключу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поправить код?

Comment: Вам нужно найти первое совпадение автора? Странная у вас get_author_id -- в параметре у вас `name`, но параметр не используется, зато внутри перебирается  словарь и возвращает первое попавшееся у себя же значение, а в `get_author_id` при наличии name вы передаете список имен :) И не понятно зачем вы про формулу описывали в вопросе, в коде не увидел упоминания )

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо большое, как всегда! Мне нужно совпадение всех авторов. Иногда это один автор, а иногда и три, и четыре.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
author_by_id = {'Пятилетова Людмила Владимировна': 80000198, 'Скрябина Алёна Вячеславовна': 80000199, 'Шавель Светлана Ивановна': 80000200}

def get_author_id(names):
    # Переберем список авторов
    for name in names:
        # При первом совпадении возвращаем id
        if name in author_by_id:
            return author_by_id[name]


result = ['Матюнин Владислав Александрович', 'Пятилетова Людмила Владимировна', 'Баутин Сергей Петрович', 'Дерябин Сергей Львович', 'Мезенцев Алексей Владимирович']
author_id = get_author_id(result)

print(author_id)  # 80000198
```

---

Для нескольких авторов (`author_by_id` и `result` в коде выше):

```
...

def get_author_id(name):
    return author_by_id.get(name)

...

for name in result:
    author_id = get_author_id(name)
    print("{:32} -> {}".format(name, author_id))
```

---

```
...

def print_authors_id(names):
    for name in names:
        author_id = get_author_id(name)
        print("{:32} -> {}".format(name, author_id))

...

print_authors_id(result)
```

Консоль:

```
Матюнин Владислав Александрович  -> None
Пятилетова Людмила Владимировна  -> 80000198
Баутин Сергей Петрович           -> None
Дерябин Сергей Львович           -> None
Мезенцев Алексей Владимирович    -> None
```

Comment: всё работает, но только для одного автора

Comment: @Ireen1985, дополнил ответ. Или нужно чтобы `get_author_id` принимала список имен и возвращала список `id` у совпавших авторов?

Comment: было бы здОрово, если бы через функцию. Но и так всё работает! Спасибо!

Comment: @Ireen1985, добавил пример `print_authors_id`. Если и это не совсем то, то опишите подробнее :)

Comment: всё хорошо!!! Просто отлично!!! Пусть будет так.